# Need flash application gui architecture advice

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need your advice on how to organize a GUI in flash application. See image:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32811/Screen%20Shot%202012-04-25%20at%2015.40.31%20.png

Application is video player. I have buttons group that must be hidden when the mouse is out of the player. I added a Sprite, and all my buttons i have added as a child of this sprite. In this case i hide the parent, rather than each button individually.

There are several problems:

- When parent Sprite resize occurred, all of his children resizes with him.
- I would like to position children relative to their container, but it is very difficult, because i can not set width and height of parent sprite.

I would like to set the width and height of the parent Sprite, position buttons inside, and any resizing in it will occur automatically.

The question is: I am using the wrong tools, or use them somehow wrong? Are there any GUI frameworks that can help with building layout?

Answer (score 1):

write this line at Creation Complete Event or any where at beginning of code

```
  fscommand("allowscale","true");
```

it will maintain aspect ratio of application so all children of application will resize and scale properly

try this it will work